# Unix command line on PC using Ubuntu

Tags: unix

I am new to these forums and to using Ubuntu and linux and UNIX. I really need some help here. I hope I haven't shot myself in the foot already. I have been trying to complete a UNIX carpentry lesson on the internet for an assignment. I am learning the basics about UNIX. I am not using a Mac, I am using a PC that I did not configure in any way (maybe that's my problem). I am using windows 10 on a lenovo and trying to the command prompt on Ubuntu to find my desktop where a file called "data-shell" is located. The problem: IT IS NOT FINDING THE DESKTOP. Upon further inspection, I have been looking through the location of my desktop and "data-shell" file and found it in the Users location under a number 12094, which I am assuming is the serial number for the computer. I have NEVER fiddled with the software at all with this computer as it cost me a lot of money, but I really do not want to be stopped in the tracks already. I have the following images numbered in the order that I discovered everything; they are posted here. I would really appreciate the help. P.S.: Since I am using a PC and not mac, I thought I had to use another command line like BASH or the terminal on my PCor doI just use Ubuntu? The UNIX shell is supposed to start with a $, right? Please correct me if I a wrong and thank you for your help

[image].
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ask this type of Question on unix.stackexchange.com or  askubuntu.com  You may get your answer there

Answer (score 0):

linux commands on windows can be ran via cmder or git bash (what i had used in past)
and in linux the desktop is at the path
/home/< username>/Desktop
whereas in windows its
C:\Users<username>\Desktop

both windows (DOS) and ubuntu/mac(linux) environment are entirely different you can directly run commands of one on the other environment, you do need to "setup" that env first if the command is not native to that.

Now, since its assignments that you are doing and all you need is bare-min linux env
you can give https://repl.it/ a try and create a new project in bash


Also, when you install Ubuntu on windows you dont get acces to windows like path, like "C:...", in ubuntu c:\ of windows is mounted to some other path in ubuntu
search on google how to access windows desktop from ubuntu shell after installing ubuntu inside of windows

Answer (score 0):

When using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), your `C` drive is located under `/mnt/c`.

Judging from the screenshot, you are user `12094`, so you can either accept this, or you need to actually configure **your** machine. Also if you look in the screenshot you provided, there is a `/home` folder which I am betting is actually pointing to `/mnt/c/`, and your home folder will be under `/home/12094`, which is also the same as what is stored in `$HOME`.

To find the location of a *file* called `data-shell`, you can run the following linux command while in your home folder:

```
find $HOME -type f -name 'data-shell'
```

This command recursively searches for files in your home directory, with the name `data-shell`

Comment: Thank you for your post but it's still not working. I put in the code that you put but it gave me the '/' symbol meaning it went back to the root directory. When I looked in the home directory, i found the directory 'ctamou', which contained "learning_vcf_file" and "miniconda3". I think it is because of the fact that the desktop is buried in a lot of directories-- is there any way I can find "Applications","Downloads", or other directories in there or am I screwed.